# Microservice program startup manager

Tags: windows, automation, offline

We have an old monolith that is being broken up into smaller processes, that run independendently and communicate with each other. We also have a (small) program that starts up these components at startup and when/if they die. We use no cloud solutions, as everything runs on a single box that is sent to the customer (along with other hardware).

Is there an off the shelf solution for the auto-start/manage other processes program?

Comment: Can you provide some details on what OS are you running in the box? Linux?

Comment: We are running windows 10. ( :( )